# Can't install gcc

Tags: 18.04, gcc

I am trying to install gcc (in order to install postGIS later), but i have the folowing problem (you can see in the picture). Can anyone help?

[image: See terminal]

Comment: Please avoid upload terminal screenshot, instead copy the output to the post.

Comment: run and post output from `apt-cache policy gcc gcc-7`

Comment: `gcc-7 7.3.0-12` looks more like a Debian package than an Ubuntu one - have you added any non-Ubuntu repositories to your apt sources?

Comment: @doug gcc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2
  Version table:
     4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
gcc-7:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.3.0-16ubuntu3
  Version table:
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` before install, to update the package repository.

Comment: @SorenA i get these: Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
3 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: @LauraA.Agalioti great .. then run `sudo apt upgrade`to install those packages. And lastly, run `sudo apt install gcc`  again.

Comment: @SorenA i take the following: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-36 linux-headers-4.15.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic linux-modules-4.15.0-36-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-36-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  curl libcurl4 libcurl4-openssl-dev
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.

Comment: @LauraA.Agalioti then run `sudo apt full-upgrade`

Comment: Issue was likely you had disabled the Security & Updates repos as gcc in 18.04 is currently at 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2.1  not 4:7.3.0-3ubuntu2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of actually held packages with:

`dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`

If there are none, or none look related, then it's probably something else. You can also try using the `aptitude` rather than `apt-get` to install your package:

`sudo aptitude install <packagename>`

Aptitude will try and find solutions which involve modifying other packages. It will also give you a detailed explanation of the problem and options for fixing it.

If you try Aptitude with `-f`, it will change its priorities and then you will obtain only those solutions which require removing/downgrading fewer packages. Here's the command:

`sudo aptitude -f install <packagename>`

**Note:** Assuming `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` is empty, Aptitude is your best solution to resolve held packages.

Source URL: [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks! I installed Aptitude and then i did sudo aptitude install <packagename>. Aptitude helped me to find solutions

Comment: Happy to help @LauraA.Agalioti.